# Access a parent class for contained class in coffeescript

Tags: oop, coffeescript

```
 class ChildItem
     constructor : ->
         @activate()
     activate : ->
         if parent.ready #this line will fail
            console.log 'activate!'

  class ParentItem
     constructor : ->
        @ready = true;
        @child = new ChildItem()

  item = new ParentItem()
```

How can I access `item.ready` from `item.child.activate` ? There has got to be a syntax for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a special syntax for this. If you need a relationship between a `ChildItem` and a `ParentItem` then you have to hook it up yourself; for example:

```
class ChildItem
    constructor: (@parent) ->
        @activate()
    activate: ->
        console.log('activate') if(@parent.ready)

class ParentItem
    constructor: ->
        @ready = true
        @child = new ChildItem(@)

item = new ParentItem()
```

Comment: Yes, it should continue to work as the child has a direct reference to the `ParentItem` in `@parent`.

Comment: Sweeet. I am going to give this a shot just to confirm.

Comment: You rock mu! This is exactly what I was looking for! also +1

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntax for magically accessing that unfortunately... Even something like `arguments.caller` wouldn't help here. However there are a couple of ways you can do it, not sure which you prefer:

1) Pass the ready argument in (or alternatively you could pass in the whole parent).

```
class ChildItem
   constructor: (ready) ->
     @activate ready
   activate: (ready) ->
     if ready
        console.log 'activate!'

class ParentItem
   constructor : ->
      @ready = true
      @child = new ChildItem(@ready)

item = new ParentItem()
```

2) Or you could use `extends` which would give the ChildItem access to all the properties and functions of the ParentItem:

```
class ParentItem
   constructor : (children) ->
      @ready = true
      @childItems = (new ChildItem() for child in [0...children])

class ChildItem extends ParentItem
   constructor: ->
     super()
     @activate()
   activate: ->
     if @ready
        console.log 'activate!'

item = new ParentItem(1)
```